# OS X Yosemite: copy / paste into shell GRASS 6.4.4. within QGIS 2.14.0

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac, copy, shell

I want to know How to copy/paste into GRASS 6.4.4. shell  within QGIS 2.14.0. 
I'm working with OS X Yosemite and the right mouse button doesn't work neither shortcut (cmd+c/cmd+v)

Comment: Try with crtl+C, ctrl+v

Comment: thank you Mehreen, I've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Often pasting into a shell is ctrl+shift+v.

Comment: thank you @MikeRSpencer I've also tried it, but it doesn't work